# Convert table contained in a string to HTML

Tags: html, email, powershell

I've got a table made out of various fields of work items. This is the table layout:

```
$table = @{Expression = {$_.Fields['Id'].Value}; Label = "Id"}, 
@{Expression = {$_.Fields['Work Item Type'].Value}; Label = "Work Item Type"}, 
@{Expression = {$_.Fields['Title'].Value}; Label = "Title"}, 
@{Expression = {$_.Fields['State'].Value}; Label = "State"},
@{Expression = {$_.Fields['Substate'].Value}; Label = "Substate"}, 
@{Expression = {$_.Fields['Assigned To'].Value}; Label = "Assigned To"}, 
@{Expression = {$_.Fields['CreatedBy'].Value}; Label = "Developer"},
@{Expression = {$_.Fields['QA Responsible'].Value}; Label = "QA Responsible"},
@{Expression = {$_.Fields['Iteration Path'].Value}; Label = "Iteration Path"}
```

and from this line of code `$workItems | Format-Table $table | Out-String` i get a table like this:

```
         Id Work Item Type  Title          State          Substate       Assigned To    Developer      QA Responsible    Iteration Path
         -- --------------  -----          -----          --------       -----------    ---------      -----------    --------------
      38479 Bug             Title1000000...Resolved       zzzzzzzzzzz... xxxxxxxxxxx... zzzzzzzzzzz... zzzzzzzzzzz     QA\2012 August
      34917 Task            Title2000000...Resolved       zzzzzzzzzzz... xxxxxxxxxxx                                  WebXXX\CCCCCC
```

But when I try to convert it to HTML I get different values. Like these here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup>
<col/>
</colgroup>
<tr><th>*</th></tr>
<tr><td>305</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

I just want to format the table in HTML and send it in an email. Can I get any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with Shay's help I figured it out. I'll post the answer here if anyone encounters similar problems. The fix was just at this line `$workItems | Format-Table $table | ConvertTo-Html`. It needed to be changed to `$workItems | Select-Object $table | ConvertTo-Html`.

Shay you helped me so much times, if you ever happen to be in Sarajevo, I'll buy you a drink :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the pipe to the `Out-String` cmdlet and try again, `Out-String` convertes your objects to a string:

```
$workItems | Format-Table $table | ConvertTo-Html
```

Comment: thanks Shay, but now i only got some GUID-like data in the table

Comment: It depends on the output of each column. If the output is a collection of items then you may see this kind of result.